# How to split a string with arbitrary arguments?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with a very simple problem.

```js
lines = "hogefoobarwai"
```

I want to cut this string into 4 characters.

Like this.

```
hoge, foob, arwa, i
```

How to split?

I try to use split() with regex.

```js
let vars = lines.match(/.{4}/g);
```

This is good. But if something like {4} is variable, it won't work.

for example

```js
 length = 6

let vars = lines.match(/.{length}/g);
```

this shows literally `/.{length}/`.

If anyone can tell me what it is, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a minimum length of one (for getting smaller substrings) and the length and build a new regular expression.

```js
const
    lines = "hogefoobarwai",
    length = 4,
    parts = lines.match(new RegExp(`.{1,${length}}`, 'g'));

console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

try using a dynamically generated Regex:

`const newRegEx = new RegEx('{' + length + '}', g)`

Comment: Close, you missed the leading period `.` and the quotes around `g`

Comment: Thanks Murlio. Problem solved. but this way won't work. (just syntaxError) maybe I'm doing it wrong. I'll try α little harder.

Comment: It work! I hadn't added the dots. Thanks!